# dual boot problems

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't boot into Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90170/cant-boot-into-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu)

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 and now windows 7 cant boot .On startup the screen showing the operating systems appears and I have selected win 7 but the system automatically boot with ubuntu .Using disc utility tool  I  can see the partitions having NTFS file systems .Please help me to fix the error. (I have tried to repair with win 7 cd) thanking you   .dilip.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using boot-repair. It's explained here:
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

You could also run this script from a live-disk [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and post back the results