# Can't boot into Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, boot, windows-7

After installing Ubuntu 11.10, I can't boot into Windows 7.
I have a new Asus laptop and after installing Ubuntu 11.10, whenever i start my laptop, I get the dual boot menu (it's heading is: `GNU GRUB Ver. 1.99-12ubuntu5`). If I just wait without touching anything the computer boots into Ubuntu, and I can start working. But if I choose the last row which reads: Windows 7 (loader)(on /dev/sda2) nothing happens, and after a while the computer boots into Ubuntu.
Someone suggested to open a terminal, type `sudo update-grub`, and enter my password. That would do the job.
I did that, but nothing changed.
Can anybody help me? I have to state that my knowledge in Ubuntu is close to zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried downloading a lightweight Linux version such as Puppy Linux(It's Ubuntu based)? My reason for mentioning it is not to install it but because you can use it to re-install GRUB and because it's Ubuntu based it will also be  able to pickup Ubuntu with no problem as well as your Win 7 install. I had a similar problem and that helped fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a Windows recovery partition (Windows recovery environment) in your grub menu?  If the answer is yes(ASUS computers usually comes with that), try running it.  Sometimes the recovery environment overwrites the MBR (mine didn't, it depends on your computer's problems), so backup your stuff in Ubuntu first.

SECOND WARNING: This may destroy your Ubuntu System(or may not)!